# Regular Expression to match "\\r"

Tags: python, regex

I'm having trouble writing a regex that matches these inputs: 
1.`\\r`
2.`\\rSomeString`

I need a regex that matches `\\r`

Comment: Could you please share some code you tried? Questions about whitespace are rather ambiguous without some code to test against.

Comment: Is your input literally "\\r", or is there a carriage return in your input?

Comment: Yes, My input is literally "\\r"

Comment: `\\\\r` should be sufficient

Comment: So you are *not* looking for matching a carriage return…

Comment: @Trey : Changed Title of question accordingly. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: So, try `r'\\\\r'` / `r'\\\\r\S*'`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/wA9iU7/3 Could you please provide the expression to match more than one time(s) [For `input 2`]

Comment: You may use [`r'\\\\r\S*'`](https://regex101.com/r/wA9iU7/5)  - one for both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape the back slashes twice. String's interpret `\` as a special character marker.

Use `\\\\r` instead. `\\` is actually interpreted as just `\`.

EDIT: So as per the comments you want any string that starts with `\\r` with any string after it. The regex pattern is as follows:

```
(\\\\r\S*)
```

`\\\\r` is the string you want at the start and `\S*` says any non-white space (`\S`) can come after any number of times (`*`).

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/wA9iU7/3 Could you please provide the expression to match more than one time(s) [For `input 2`]

Comment: So you'd like to match anything that starts with `\\r`? Or anything with `\\r` anywhere in the string?

Comment: Are you trying to find the first word in a paragraph?

Comment: No, my list contains entries beginning with `\\r` or `\\rWithStrings` or both. Just trying to match pattern and replace them.

Comment: Use the pattern above it will match any of it. Do you need code? It works on Python on my machine using `re.sub`

Answer (score 1):

A literal backslash in Python can be matched with `r'\\'` (note the use of the raw string literal!). You have two literal backslashes, thus, you need 4 backslashes (in a raw string literal) before `r`.

Since you may have any characters after `\\r`, you may use

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'\\\\r\S*')
test_str = r"\\r \\rtest"
print(p.findall(test_str))
```

See [Python demo](http://ideone.com/kUK56Q)

**Pattern description**:

- `\\\\` - 2 backslashes
- `r`  - a literal `r`
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace characters.

*Variations*:

- If the characters after `r` can only be alphanumerics or underscore, use `\w*` instead of `\S*`
- If you want to only match `\\r` before non-word chars, add a `\B` non-word boundary before the backslashes in the pattern.

Comment: That is how I understand the question and [OP's demo](https://regex101.com/r/wA9iU7/3) where two literal backslashes are used in the input string. I did not post since I did not have any confirmation on what there is in the input. So, judging by that demo, there are 2 literal backslashes. I cannot be too sure, I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can fine-tune your *regular expressions* on-line, e.g. at [this site](https://regex101.com/#python).